# IIS shows blank page: Hosting WebAPI locally (for using out of the router)

Tags: .net, iis

Problem: While Adding a website (project dir+html test client) to IIS Manager 6.1 on Win7, the page is shown blank on firefox. Not even an error message is being shown.

General Background:
I have a Java client application for android that should read information from a WebAPI application.
Now, before i'm purchasing any server, I would like to use my own computer as the server.
I've understood hosting a WebAPI can be done through self hosting (Console/WindowsService)
or by web hosting (IIS Server).

I want to use IIS Manager / IIS Express in order to host the WebAPI,
but to expose it to the "out side word". That's way I'll be able to access information from testing the Android Client on my own Galaxy, or by friends that I would like to examine the application.

But I can't really manage this.
I mean, everything is fine while I'm doing ctrl+F5 on VisualStudio.
But my purpose is to be able doing that without any dependance on visual studio,
and, of course, latter to expose it and be able to get information to my own Android.

When I'm trying to add a new website to IIS Manager 6.1, I'm specifing the path of my WebAPI project (which contains html+jQuery test) it shows a blank page on fire fox.

Why does IIS Manager is so tough to handle?

Answer (score 1):

Recently ran into this problem using IIS on Win7 --- found a solution that [solved the problem here](http://forums.asp.net/post/4202386.aspx) ---

If after deploying a Web API project to IIS you see only a blank page, simply go to the ApplicationPool for your website in IIS > right-click > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity

Change that value to a user account with Admin privileges ---> as noted in the link above, this is likely not a good idea for production code; but it can, at least, solve the problem for local development - if you manage to run into it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the OP, but still cannot figure out. Everything it returns is a blank page.
Tried your method too, but I think I don't have enough privilege to do that (my computer account is a domain account)

Comment: If you have tried running through the Debugger and that works (just like it did for the OP and me), then the issue is privileges - the Process Model for this particular scenario needs Admin privileges to work.  @Hoàng, you might be able to make a local admin account (instead of domain account) to get around this issue.

Comment: thank you, I was able to get around this issue indeed. Not remembering how I did it, but in the end it's a matter of combining all the related IIS solutions, including yours. Look like IIS 7 isn't the ideal host for Web API, since it requires quite a hell of configuration for such simple things. I decide to move on to use self-hosting now.